# How to create an array from hash replacing all of the keys and values with integers

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
a = {"0" => ["2", "3"], "1" => "4", "3" => "5"}
```

and I need a function to make an array from it:

```
a = [[2, 3], 4, nil, 5]
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Not clear. Especially, where does `nil` come from? Why is it not `[nil, [2, 3], 4, nil, 5]`, or `[[2, 3], 4, nil, 5, nil]`, or `[[2, 3], 4, nil, 5, nil, nil]`?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect you to have tried, and tried again, and when you've exhausted trying after many times, that you'll ask, you'll show us a summarized version of what you tried and explain why it didn't work. We want to see the minimal code you wrote trying to solve the problem, along with why it didn't work. You don't need "UPD:", we can see what you've changed. Read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: You may confuse your readers by naming a hash `a` (or an array `h`, a string `i` or a fixnum `s`). Also, it's generally not good practice to set a variable equal to a hash then reuse the same variable to point to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we make a range from 0 to the maximum key value (as an integer)
Then for each number we fetch the value in "a" at the corresponding key.
If the value is an array, we convert it into an array of integers
if not, convert it into an integer (unless it's false or nil).

```
a = {"0" => ["2", "3"], "1" => "4", "3" => "5"}
a = (0..(a.keys.map(&:to_i).max)).map do |v|
  x = a[v.to_s]
  x.is_a?(Array) ? x.map(&:to_i) : (x && x.to_i)
end
```

**A better version that can handle a minimum key > "0"**

```
a = a.values_at(*Range.new(*a.keys.minmax_by(&:to_i))).map do |v|
  v.is_a?(Array) ? v.map(&:to_i) : (v && v.to_i)
end

a
=> [[2, 3], 4, nil, 5]
```

minmax returns an array that we explode into arguments to Range.new
We then explode that range into arguments for values_at.

```
[*Range.new(*["2","8"])]
=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

Comment: I think it is just coincidence that the size of `0..(a.size)` matches the size of the expected array. What if the number of elements skipped in the original hash were two?

Comment: @sawa you are right, don't know what I was thinking, fixed!

Comment: Code only-answers, like no-code at all answers, are discouraged. Please explain why this is usable, and/or, the right answer. You're not only answering the OP's question, but helping anyone in the future searching for the solution to the same question. Teach them to fish, just don't toss out a fish to satisfy this particular problem.

Comment: 1. Why do you assume the smallest key (after conversion to an integer) is `0`, but you compute the largest key? (True, the OP's example had `"0"` as the smallest key, but that's just an example.) 2. You can simplify by replacing your second line with `("0"..a.max_by(&:to_i)).map { |v|` and replacing the following line with `x=a[v]`.

Comment: Note `["1", "12", "3"]. minmax #=> ["1", "3"]`. You need `a.keys.minmax_by(&:to_I)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Haha, indeed! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
min, max = a.keys.minmax_by(&:to_i)

min.upto(max).map do |key|
  a[key].respond_to?(:map) ? a[key].map(&:to_i) : a[key].to_i if a[key]
end # => [[2, 3], 4, nil, 5]
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko seems someone is systematically downvoting all answers in this (rather flawed) question.

Comment: The system will catch people who are systematically down voting others. Sometimes people get a whole bag-full of down votes and decide to dump them on something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it really makes sense to have the array that you have as the final output given that now you don't know for sure which element corresponds to which question.

If we simplify the problem that you want to convert the hash keys and values to numeric and add the missing keys, then you can do the following with help of Rails' Active Support Hash extension:

```
# Below require needed only if code is not being used in Rails app
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"

a = {"0" => ["2", "3"], "1" => "4", "3" => "5"}

p a.deep_merge(a) {|_,v,_| v.to_i rescue v.map(&:to_i)}
   .transform_keys(&:to_i)
   .tap { |h| h.reverse_update (h.keys.min..h.keys.max).zip([nil]).to_h }
   .sort {|a,b| a <=> b}  # Not really needed
   .to_h                  # Not really needed

#=> {0=>[2, 3], 1=>4, 2=>nil, 3=>5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`Hash.values`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) though you won't get that nil there:

```
a = {"0" => ["2", "3"], "1" => "4", "3" => "5"}
def deep_map(h)
  h.map{|i| i.is_a?(String) ? i.to_i : deep_map(i)}
end
deep_map (a.values)
```

gives:

```
[[2, 3], 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are OK with the sample input. I didn't test any other cases:

```
a = {"0" => ["2", "3"], "1" => "4", "3" => "5"}

('0'..a.size.to_s).map do |i| 
  v = ([a[i]].flatten.map { |i| i && i.to_i })
  v.size == 1 ? v[0] : v
end
# => [[2, 3], 4, nil, 5]
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but your answer isn't correct, it returns strings

Comment: @BjörnNilsson you're totally right, thanks. The fixed version isn't very elegant (pretty nasty looking, really), but it meets OPs specification. I edited my answer.

Comment: If `a = { '0'=>'1', '99'=>'2' }`, your method would return `[1, nil, nil]`. I don't believe that's what the OP wants.More generally, should we infer that `n x n` equals `1` because `1 x 1` equals `1`?

Answer (score 0):

I'v split out the conversion of strings to a separate method (`fixnumify`) because it does not seem to be an essential element of the question:

```
a = {"0" => ["2", "3"], "1" => "4", "3" => "5"}

def fixnumify(obj)
  case obj
  when Array then obj.map(&:to_i)
  when String then obj.to_i
  else obj
  end
end

from, to = a.keys.minmax_by(&:to_i)
  #=> [0, 3]
a.values_at(*from..to).map { |v| fixnumify(v) }
  #=> [[2, 3], 4, nil, 5]
```